# Custom URLs between different post types, using "Pods"

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, pods-framework

### Setup

I am using the plugin Pods, and I have created 2 custom post types: `location` and `office`.

[image]

The URLs to access these resources are, for example:

- `/location/new-york` (for locations)
- `/office/my-ny-office` (for offices)

### My goal

There is a bidirectional relationship 1:M between them (1 location can have multiple offices)

[image]

I want to change the URL for each office, with the format `/location/location-slug/office-slug`, so that the URL reflects in location assigned to that office

Example: `/location/new-york/my-ny-office`

To do this, I went to "Advanced options" in my `office` post type, and I added `/location/%location%` to the **Custom Rewrite Slug**

[image]

And then, I added this code to my `functions.php`

```php
function office_permalink_structure($post_link, $post) {
    if (is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'office') {
        $office_pod = pods('office', $post->ID);
        $location = $office_pod->field('location');
        if ($location) {
            return str_replace('%location%', $location['post_name'], $post_link);
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'office_permalink_structure', 10, 2);
```

Which is meant to search for the appropriate location, to replace the placeholder `%location%`.

### The problem

When I try to open the page corresponding to each office post, I land in a 404 error.

This is, I suspect, because it conflicts with the URL rules to display the locations `/location/new-york`. This suspicion is due to the fact that if I change the value of the **Custom Rewrite Slug** to something like `foo/%location%`, everything works as intended.

I thought that setting support for "hierarchy" to the `office` post type might be a solution, but since `office` and `location` are different post types, I do not seem to be able to set up this relationship.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Is the `location` CPT hierarchical? If so, try turning that off. You may have better success adding your own custom rewrite rules in addition to the default permalink structure.